# Checking existance of long chain of associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm writing an action for that involves a long chain of associations, something like:

```ruby
@featured_image = @content_page.content_tree_item.children.first.featured_images.first
```

I would like to get `@featured_image = nil` if any of these associations doesn't exist.  I can do:

```ruby
@featured_image = @content_page.content_tree_item.children.first.featured_images.first rescue nil
```

But blanketing the entire chain in a `rescue` seems hackish and might mask other problems.  Is there a "rails way", or at least a better way, to do this that only catches the non-existance of an association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) or `try`.

That said, in general, trainwrecks like this are often a sign that something fairly high up has too much knowledge of something down fairly low, and some refactoring or delegation might be in order.

Comment: Yeah, probably.  In any case, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.